# in radio form using css input[type="radio"] checked not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I created a mood barometer with a radio form and want to keep only `img` as a selector. When I hover and press the image I want to keep it bigger when selected. With hover it works but when pressed doesn't keep its size.

I've tried with `input[type="radio"]:checked` and focus, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas? I cant change the HTML code because its a WordPress plugin (Forminator), I can only change the CSS.

```css
.forminator-radio .forminator-radio-bullet {
  position: absolute !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}

.forminator-radio .forminator-radio-label img.emoji {
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 40px !important;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.forminator-radio .forminator-radio-label img.emoji:hover,
.forminator-radio-label:focus {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 60px !important;
}
```

```html
<div role="radiogroup" class="forminator-field" aria-labelledby="forminator-poll-68326--title">
  <label for="68326-0-answer-1" class="forminator-radio">
    <input id="68326-0-answer-1" type="radio" data-required="" name="68326" value="answer-1">
    <span class="forminator-radio-bullet" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="forminator-radio-label">
      <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f641.svg">
    </span>
  </label>
  <label for="68326-0-answer-2" class="forminator-radio">
    <input id="68326-0-answer-2" type="radio" data-required="" name="68326" value="answer-2">
    <span class="forminator-radio-bullet" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="forminator-radio-label">
      <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f610.svg">
    </span>
  </label>
  <label for="68326-0-answer-3" class="forminator-radio">
    <input id="68326-0-answer-3" type="radio" data-required="" name="68326" value="answer-3">
    <span class="forminator-radio-bullet" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="forminator-radio-label">
      <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f642.svg">
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can use an additional rule which sets the emoji size when the input is checked:

```css
.forminator-radio input:checked ~ .forminator-radio-label img.emoji
```

This selector targets any checked radio input, then retrieves the `label` sibling and finally it's child `img`.

Here's a working example:

```css
.forminator-radio .forminator-radio-bullet {
  position: absolute !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}

.forminator-radio .forminator-radio-label img.emoji {
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 40px !important;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.forminator-radio .forminator-radio-label img.emoji:hover,
.forminator-radio input:checked ~ .forminator-radio-label img.emoji,
.forminator-radio-label:focus {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 60px !important;
}
```

```html
<div role="radiogroup" class="forminator-field" aria-labelledby="forminator-poll-68326--title">
  <label for="68326-0-answer-1" class="forminator-radio">
    <input id="68326-0-answer-1" type="radio" data-required="" name="68326" value="answer-1">
    <span class="forminator-radio-bullet" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="forminator-radio-label">
      <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f641.svg">
    </span>
  </label>
  <label for="68326-0-answer-2" class="forminator-radio">
    <input id="68326-0-answer-2" type="radio" data-required="" name="68326" value="answer-2">
    <span class="forminator-radio-bullet" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="forminator-radio-label">
      <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f610.svg">
    </span>
  </label>
  <label for="68326-0-answer-3" class="forminator-radio">
    <input id="68326-0-answer-3" type="radio" data-required="" name="68326" value="answer-3">
    <span class="forminator-radio-bullet" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="forminator-radio-label">
      <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f642.svg">
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

One thing to note here is that I would strongly suggest you stop using `!important` everywhere. Use selector specificity to override, not flags.

Comment: thank you! you saved me my sunday ;D